# Slim framework and .htaccess URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, slim

I am creating a web API using Slim framework and now trying to rewrite the URL. I have wampp installed and have the following folder structure

```
E:\wamp\www\
    .htaccess
    E:\wamp\www\SlimTest\
        index.php
        .htaccess (not sure if I really need one at this level...)
```

Without any URL rewriting, I can access the Slim script by going to: http://localhost/SlimTest/index.php

Inside the index.php, I have a very simple Slim script:

```
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response->write("Hello " . $args['name']);
});
```

And to access the /hello/name URI, without any rewrite, I type: http://localhost/SlimTest/index.php/hello/JoeDoe

What I want to achieve is to have the URL: http://localhost/slim/api/v1 URL redirecting everything to: http://localhost/SlimTest/index.php and everything **after** the index.php string is seen as the search query (so it reaches `$app->get('/hello/{name}'`, properly)

Currently, the .htaccess at /www level has the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/slim/api/v1/(.*)
RewriteRule ^slim/api/v1/(.*)$ /SlimTest/index.php/$1  [QSD,L]
```

When I test the URL http://localhost/slim/api/v1/hello/John for example, the request is indeed taken to index.php. But, I've printed out the URI and what I got was:

```
echo 'current uri ' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
"current uri /slim/api/v1/hello/John"
```

So, as you can see, the wholr /slim/api/v1/hello/John is taken as URI to the PHP script, while I want only everything after /v1/ to be taken to the script as URI...

Hope this makes sense. Can any one give me some direction, please?

Comment: if the route is working then why do you need the shorter uri

Comment: @Scriptonomy - Not sure if I understand your question.
I dont want the http://localhost/SlimTest/index.php/hello/JoeDoe URL... that's not user friendly. I want http://localhost/slim/api/v1/hello/John

Comment: If you move your htaccess to the one in E:\wamp\www\SlimTest\ then it should work, otherwise you can set RewriteBase to /slim/api/v1/ and it should work, more information on RewriteBase here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html